# Unlocked Phenom II X2 vs. Athlon II X4 performance

Tags: cpu

I have a friend who is debating what kind of CPU he wants for his MSI 880GMA-E45 motherboard. There's the option of getting an Athlon quad-core, but seeing as the board has capabilities to unlock hidden cores on Phenom processors.

Would it be a more bang-for-buck solution to purchase a Phenom II X2 dual-core and unlock cores to use it as a quad-core? Comparing unlocked Phenom II X2 with Athlon II X4 processors of equal frequency, would the unlocked Phenom technically have better performance since there is more cache on Phenoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indeed you can unlock the extra cores on the Phenom, I would expect it to do better.  However, your ability to unlock those cores is far from guaranteed — they are usually locked for a reason, and often end up not functional.

Answer (score -1):

Yes in many apps the larger L2/L3 cache helps.  It is true that some don't have viable disabled cores but they are not usually locked for a reason.  More often than not, say 75% of the time, they are fine, possibly just needing a slight voltage boost to operate at the same speed if you buy a high bin Phenom instead of a low bin.

There is no reason to fear this, try it and see.  Additionally, you need to consider whether your apps are multi-core optimized and how well they are.  Many high end modern apps are but most older apps run with only one or two threads so they would be faster on 2 phenom II cores than 4 Athlon II cores, because they're just not using all 4 cores.